# JXLS Formula not grouping output by specified field

Tags: java, excel, jxl, jxls

I am creating a report and I need to output my data structure to an excel spreadsheet. For this, I am using JXLS but am having trouble with creating the jx formula to output the data properly.

I have a list of type person:

```
 List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Within my Person class it has the following attributes:

```
String name;
String age;
List<Pet> listOfPets;
```

For some fake data I am using:

```
petList1.add("Dog");
petList1.add("Cat");
people.add(new Person("Joseph", "18", petList1);

petList2.add("Dog");
petList2.add("Fish");
people.add(new Person("Tommy", "18", petList2);

petList3.add("Bird");
petList3.add("Dog");
people.add(new Person("Sally", "19", petList3);
```

I want this to showup in Excel as grouped by age. So for example:

```
Age 18:
      Name: Joseph
      Age: 18
      Pets: Dog, Cat
      ----------------
      Name: Tommy
      Age: 18
      Pets: Dog, Fish

Age 19:
      Name: Sally
      Age: 19
      Pets: Bird, Dog
```

What I have so far is this:

```
<jx:forEach items="${personsList}" var="person"> groupBy="${person.age}"                
Name :   ${person.name}
Age  :   ${person.age}          
<jx:forEach items="${person.listOfPets}" var="pets">                
Pets :  ${pets.type},
</jx:forEach>               
</jx:forEach>
```

The above does output the correct data but it isn't grouping it by age... It's showing up as a large list of repeating ages? How can I get this to group all under specific age?

Comment: Have you taken a thorough look through the JXLS library documentation? I don't have time to figure this out for you, but that would be the place to start. And if the JXLS library doesn't have the features you need, you may consider looking for another library.

Comment: I've been through the documentation multiple times and I figured the groupBy would work. But unfortunately it's not doing what I expect and there are not many examples to work from

Comment: I've used other Excel libraries in the past where you built out your Excel document cell by cell. If you found one that worked that way (or if this one does that) you could perform the group by programmatically rather than relying on built-in features.

Comment: Any library recommendations?

Comment: No specific recommendations and I can't find the names of those I've used off-hand. Should be tons of them, though. Something simple will probably do, unless other specs for your assignment get too complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *groupBy="age"* instead of *groupBy="${person.age}"* as explained in [Jxls 1.x documentation](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/1.x/reference/tags.html).

However the strategic recommendation is to use [Jxls-2](http://jxls.sourceforge.net) and its [Each-command](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/each_command.html) to do the grouping instead of the legacy Jxls-1 which is unsupported.

Comment: Do not understand the recommendation when the v1.x is more usable and smarter than v2.x, from my point of view :(